# UIWebView loadRequest with no parent

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I created a `UIWebView` and called `[webview loadRequest:url]`. When the webview has no superview/parent, `[webview isLoading]` returns false constantly and the `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` delegate is never called.

However if I do:  `self.view = webview;`  or add it to my current GUI, the `[isLoading]` returns true and the delegate is called..

Is there any way to get it to load the request FIRST, call the delegate, and then I can display it after knowing that it successfully loaded?

Comment: Just add the UIWebview on you view and [webView setHidden:YES] until  loading done.

Comment: Ahh.. That works. A bit annoying to have to do but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially keep your webView hidden `[myWebView setHidden:true]` once `webViewDidFinishLoad` called set `[myWebView setHidden:false]`

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) UIWebView *myWebView;
```

.m

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    if (webView == myWebView) {
        [webView setHidden:false];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [myWebView setDelegate:(id)self];
    [myWebView setHidden:true];
    [myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://apple.com"]]];

}
```